# In Atom TextEditor, what does an orange "Enabled" button denote when viewing packages?

Tags: atom-editor

I notice that I'm not getting any markdown syntax highlighting in Atom. So I had a look at the Core module: language-gfm. When I press the *Enable* button nothing happens. Am I missing something? Or is something wrong with my install?

[image]

Comment: The orange is the indicator for `is-disabled`, nothing more. Have a look at the console if there are any errors reported.

Comment: Ah yes. There are are no errors, but something is definitely broken. Thanks